# Can I execute a Python script from Pure Data?

Tags: python, osc, puredata

I know there are some tools out there for using Pure Data(Pd) within Python, so you can program and use Pd without using its GUI. I was wondering if anyone has tried the opposite. I want to send sequencing information into Python and process it with my Python script. Then I want to send the information to Pd.

So far I have written sequences to text files using the [msgfile] object in Pd. These can be opened and manipulated with Python but this involves switching to IDLE and manually running the program, writing out to a text file again, and finally reading from the file in Pd. If Pd can execute Python scripts this would save me the effort of writing my own objects in C or C++ or switching between programs and manually running my scripts.

Comment: Have you looked into pyext? http://grrrr.org/research/software/py/

Comment: Running both at the same time and using socket messages to communicate might be an option. See [How to send messages from Pure Data to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285324/how-to-send-messages-from-pure-data-to-python) and  [Pure Data on Mac OS X - how to send messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097175/pure-data-on-mac-os-x-how-to-send-messages/24886508#24886508)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can execute python scripts from within Pure Data with the pyext external by Thomas Grill: http://grrrr.org/research/software/py/